# Parsing Xml fails in Lwuit J2ME application on some simulators

Tags: xml, parsing, java-me, sdk, lwuit

I have a LWUIT j2me application that parses a local XML.
I tried my code on the (Java TM Platform Micro SDK 3.0  DefultFxPhone 1)
and on the asha simulator (Nokia_SDK_1_1_Java).
Also I tested the code on different devices and it works fine.
But, when I tested it on the (Nokia_SDK_2_0_Java simulator Nokia Asha 305) the condition in the while loop is always false.I think that there is something wrong with the parser.
Any help?
How can I figure out why do this problem happen only in the parser with this SDK.
and i get this exception on the parseEvent event=Parser.read();

```
java.io.IOException
at com.sun.cldc.io.ResourceInputStream.read(+104)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:99)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(+11)
at org.kxml.parser.XmlParser.peekChar(+36)
at org.kxml.parser.XmlParser.peek(+68)
at org.kxml.parser.XmlParser.read(+11)
```

Here is the parsing code :

```
   Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");

   XmlParser parser=new XmlParser(reader);
   Vector items = new Vector();
   String tipId;
   String Text;
   String tipImage;
   String cateId = null;
   String cateName;
   String objId = null;
   String objName;

   ParseEvent event = parser.read();
   ParseEvent readTextEvent = null;
   while (event.getType() != Xml.END_DOCUMENT) {
          switch (event.getType()) {
             case Xml.START_TAG:

                  if (event.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Category")){
                    cateId=event.getAttribute("id").getValue();

                }

                if (event.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("object")){

                    objId=event.getAttribute("id").getValue();

                }

                if (event.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Tip")){
                    if(CategoryId.equals(cateId) && objectId.equals(objId)) 
                    {

                     readTextEvent=parser.read();
                     bean=new bean();
                     isItem=true;

                    }

                }
                if (isItem &&event.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("text")){
                     readTextEvent=parser.read();
                     Text = readTextEvent.getText();
                     bean.setTipText(Text);



                }

                 if (isItem &&event.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Image")){
                     readTextEvent=parser.read();
                     tipImage = readTextEvent.getText();

                     bean.setTipImage(tipImage);
                     isItem=false;
                     items.addElement(bean);

                }

               break;
               case Xml.END_TAG:
                 if (event.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Tip")) {

                     bean = null;
                     isItem = false;
                   }
                 break;
                case Xml.TEXT:
                break;
             }
          event = null;
          event = parser.read();

          }
```

Comment: Please add the code for parser initialization.

Comment: Done.I added the parser initialization.

Comment: The problem might be with the initialization of in variable. Can you also add its code?

Comment: but the code works fine on different simulators, i don't think it might be with the initialization of variables , but i will add the code.

Comment: I know that the Nokia 2.0 emulator has some high level SDK's included, it could be that it is importing from its own library instead of yours? Just a thought, check the import statements and the included JSR's in the project.

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlParser`from LWUIT/[CodenameOne](http://www.codenameone.com/) doesn't have a read method. The stack you provided seems incomplete since its missing your calls to the read method.